# Pageref, Index, Glossary? Multiple plant species list

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, indexing

I need to make a plant list of all the species in the book. 
The list has to be repeated twice with a different order:

1. Once alphabetically by common name with the following structure: Common name, *Species name*, page number(s);
2. Once alphabetically by species name with the following structure: *Species name*, Common name, page number(s);

Here is my attempt with `imakeidx` (MWE), may be a clumsy one, but i'm open to suggestion since it's a big book (700 pages) and it's best to find the smoothest way from the beginning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex [name=com-sp,title=List of plants mentioned in text by comon name]
\makeindex [name=sp-com,title=List of plants mentioned in text by species name]

\begin{document}

\section{Text}

Here you can plant para grass\index[com-sp]{Para grass, \textit{Brachiaria mutica}}\index[sp-com]{\textit{Brachiaria mutica}, Para Grass}, and then\textit{Abelmosphus esculentus}\index[com-sp]{Okra, \textit{Abelmosphus esculentus}}\index[sp-com]{\textit{Abelmosphus esculentus}, Okra}


\lipsum[1-6]

Here you can plant para grass\index[com-sp]{Para grass, \textit{Brachiaria mutica}}\index[sp-com]{\textit{Brachiaria mutica}, Para Grass}, and then\textit{Abelmosphus esculentus}\index[com-sp]{Okra, \textit{Abelmosphus esculentus}}\index[sp-com]{\textit{Abelmosphus esculentus}, Okra}

\printindex [com-sp]
\printindex [sp-com]

\end{document}
```

[image: list by common name]
[image: list by species name]

---

Old Question was:

I need to list all page numbers where a certain label occours (separated by commas).

I know that `\pageref` gives just one page number and that `\label` should be unique, but I don't find any alternative way.

Here in MWE, I should get

> Trigonella 1,3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\section{Text}

Trigonella \label{001}

\lipsum[1-12]



Trigonella\label{001}

\lipsum[1-6]



\section{List of plants}

trigonella \pageref{001} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: How about using a glossary/the `glossaries` package?

Comment: If using `\label` you certainly need to make the labels unique as if you do not (and you ignore the resulting error)  then latex will only have information about one of the points, all the others will be lost as the label information is saved in a macro with name constructed from the label

Comment: however `\label` seems to be the wrong thing here, do you not want `\index{Trigonella}`  ?

Comment: Both glossary and  index seem not to be ok for me, as i need to repeat the same plant list different times with different  orders (e.g. by common name,  by species name) and i think would be simplier just to have a way to print all page numbers where a certain species occours.  I know that \label could not be the solution

Comment: that is exactly what `\index` is for you can use `... common name\index{speciesname}.... species\index{speciesname} .... some passing reference that doesn't explicitly name it at all\index{speciesname}`   and then all three references will appear in the index under speciesname

Comment: I suggest the glossaries package anyway, where a specific glossary style could be used in order to display in one style and use another one for another kind of sorting etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. But i need to display the list twice: once in  alphabetical order by common name (listing: common name, species name, page numbers), the other in alphabetical order by species name (listing: species name, common names, page numbers). Since, as you seem to know, the same species can have different common names, do you figure out a way to achieve this?

Comment: please fix your question and example, no one would guess that requirement from the current question.

Comment: ok i'm working on it with index and glossary, after that I'll close this question and open a new one. So I assume there is no simple solution to just list multiple page numbers of a single element occouring multiple time, right?

Comment: @peppino, you can print the Index many times, don't worry.

Comment: what do you mean by "no simple solution" ?  That is what `\index` does (although perhaps you consider that not simple)

Comment: @David,  if I would have  something like`\pageref` i could just write down the list in a normal text and customize it easily in a number of ways, I don't need the list to be automatically generated. If I get it right (I'm studying `imakeidx` package, I'm fairly new to it) I can just print the whole list as `\printindex` and control everything (sorting, style, ecc) through this package, there is no way to have the pages of a single item printed (like in the example with trigonella). Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: eek the fact that you would want to construct the list by hand had not even occurred to me:-) In that case just use different labels in each case `\label{trigonella -1}`, `\label{trigonella -2}`, ... maintaining such a list would be tiresome and error prone but easy, so it's your choice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but in this case I would have to write `\pageref{trigonella -1}`, `\pageref{trigonella -2}`... so no way to get just all the trigonella page numbers without printing a whole index (but thanks for your answers!)

Comment: Question updated with a new MWE using `imakeidx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative method that uses [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). Each plant type is defined in a `.bib` file using `@dualentry`. For example, `plants.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@dualentry{paragrass,
 name={para grass},
 description={Brachiaria mutica}
}

@dualentry{okra,
 name={okra},
 description={Abelmosphus esculentus}
}
```

The document source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[record,% use bib2gls
 nomain,% don't create 'main' glossary
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
 stylemods={mcols},% patch styles and load glossary-mcols.sty
 style=mcolindex,% set default style
 postpunc=comma% put a comma after the description
]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{common}{List of Plants (by Common Name)}
\newglossary*{species}{List of Plants (by Species Name)}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={plants}, % terms defined in plants.bib
  type={common}, % put primary terms in the 'common' glossary
  dual-type={species}, % put dual terms in the 'species' glossary
  category={common}, % assign category for primary terms
  dual-category={species}, % assign category for dual terms
  combine-dual-locations=both % combine primary and dual locations
]

% provide convenient command to access dual entries
% (\species[options]{label}[insert] behaves like \gls[options]{dual.label}[insert])    
\glsxtrnewgls{dual.}{\species}

% provide semantic formatting command    
\newcommand{\speciesfmt}[1]{\emph{#1}}

% formatting attributes:
\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{glossdescfont}{speciesfmt}
\glssetcategoryattribute{species}{glossnamefont}{speciesfmt}
\glssetcategoryattribute{species}{textformat}{speciesfmt}

% case-changing attributes (adjusts glossary style):
\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{glossname}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{species}{glossname}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{species}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

% minor adjustments to the tree-like styles:

% don't use bold for the name in the glossary 
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}

% put a comma and space before the description
\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{,\space}

\begin{document}
\section{Text}

Here you can plant \gls{paragrass}, and then \species{okra}.

\lipsum[1-6]

Here you can plant \gls{paragrass}, and then \species{okra}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

The common name is referenced (and indexed) using `\gls` and the species is referenced (and indexed) using `\species`. (The label can't contain spaces or special characters.) The line with the references appears as:

[image: Here you can plant para grass, and then Abelmosphus esculentus.]

The two glossaries appear as:

[image: List of Plants (by Common Name) Okra, Abelmosphus esculentus, 1, 2 Para grass, Brachiaria mutica, 1, 2 List of Plants (by Species Name) Abelmosphus esculentus, Okra, 1, 2 Brachiaria mutica, Para grass, 1, 2]

If the document file is called `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

If you want letter groups you need to add `-g` or `--group` to the `bib2gls` call and change the style to `mcolindexgroup`.

Comment: do you think `\makenoidxglossaries`option will get to slow with about 1000 entries (in a 700 pages document) compared to `bib2gls`?

Comment: @peppino Definitely. I did some testing for my article "Testing indexes: testidx.sty" for the latest TUGBoat issue (Volume 38 Number 3, 2017) and the document build times for a test document generated with [`testidx-glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/testidx) were around 3.5 minutes for `\makenoidxglossaries` and around 5 seconds for `bib2gls`. This was for approximately 580 entries so 1000 entries will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

That's an alternative using `glossaries` which I find to be more convenient.

Instead of using two commands `\index` each time a plant occour in the document, this method creates a unique glossary with two display styles (the use of `\gls`is pretty handful during the document)

"name" field is used for common name
"description" field is used for species name

Using `\makenoidxglossaries`allows a mixture of sort methods as described in [user manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1).

Glossary entries are defined alphabetically by species name so this order can be used setting `sort=def` for `\printnoidxglossary`

[image: double plant list]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nomain, nogroupskip]{glossaries}


\newglossary{plants}{pli}{plo}{Plants}


\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{001}{%
  type=plants,
  name={Okra},
  description={Abelmosphus esculentus},
}

\newglossaryentry{002}{%
  type=plants,
  name={Para grass},
  description={Brachiaria mutica},
}




% First Glossary style (common name, species name
\newglossarystyle{com-sp}{%
 \setglossarystyle{index}
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
   ,\space \textit{\glossentrydesc{##1}},\space##2 \par
 }%
}


% Second Glossary style (species name, common name)
\newglossarystyle{sp-com}{%
 \setglossarystyle{index}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \glsentryitem{##1}\textit{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentrydesc{##1}}}%
   ,\space \glossentryname{##1},\space##2 \par
 }%
}



\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}



\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%

\gls{001}% Mention okra here

\blindtext[10]

\gls{002}% Mention para grass here

\clearpage

}



\setglossarystyle{com-sp}
\printnoidxglossary[type=plants, sort=word,title=List of plants mentioned in text by common name]
\setglossarystyle{sp-com}
\printnoidxglossary[type=plants, sort=def,title=List of plants mentioned in text by species name]


\end{document}
```